# Characterization of a subfield $K \varsubsetneq \mathbb {C}$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Characterize $x \in \mathbb R$ such that there exist a subfield $K \varsubsetneq \mathbb C$ such that $K(x) = \mathbb C$.

-All subfields $K$ of $\mathbb{C}$ contain $\mathbb Q$, then all $x\notin \mathbb Q$

-If there exist $K$, it is uncountable. In fact if $K(x)= \mathbb {C}$ is countable, which is absurd.

But this is not enough to characterize all the x..,

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Would $x$ rather be algebraic or transcendent over $\Bbb Q$? (If transcendent, what should we do with $\sqrt x$, e.g.?)

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered with elementary means. Elementary in the sense of not needing stuff like Artin-Schreier (proving that $K$ has to be isomorphic to, but not equal to, the field of real numbers). See Joy-Joy's answer. I would be happy to be proven wrong though.

Comment: @Hurkyl You had posted a solution no?

Comment: I think the following characterizes $x$. Either $x$ is transcendental or, if it is algebraic with minimal polynomial $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, then the splitting field extension of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ has even order. This can be done using a bit of Galois theory to show that $K$ exists in the case that the condition is satisfied, and the Artin-Schreier theorem in the case that it isn't.

Comment: Actually my comment above is not correct. In fact the field $K$ exists if and only if $x$ is not a totally real algebraic number.

Comment: Btw, I don't think it is possible to prove this while completely avoiding the use of Zorn's lemma. To construct $K$ you either have to find an isomorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ taking $x$ to a non-real (and then let $K$ be the preimage of the reals), which requires the axiom of choice (in the form of Zorn's lemma most likely), or you want to define $K$ to be a maximal subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ not containing $x$ which again uses Zorn's lemma.

Comment: @GeorgeLowther You have right Zorn's lemma is in my cursus. Do you have a solution?

Comment: @GeorgeLowther Have seen my comments ?

Comment: @Nico: Yes. I'm not sure if I could give a proof avoiding Galois theory, Artin-schreier, or similar. I'll give it some thought

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Denote by $E$ the set of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying your conditions.

- If $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$ or algebraic not totally real, then $x \in E$.

> Take $y=i \pi$ if $x$ is transcendental or $y \notin \mathbb{R}$ conjugate to $x$ if $x$ is algebraic not totally real. Using Zorn's lemma you can find an automorphism $\varphi$ of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\phi(y)=x$. Take $K:=\phi(\mathbb{R})$. Then $K[x] = \varphi(\mathbb{R}[y])=\mathbb{C}$

- If $x$ is algebraic totally real, then $x \notin E$.

> Unfortunately I don't know how to do it without Artin-Schreier. Recall that Artin-Schreier states that if $K \subset \mathbb{C}$ is such that $[\mathbb{C}:K]<\infty$ then there exists an automorphism $\varphi$ of $\mathbb{C}$ inducing an isomorphism $\varphi : \mathbb{R} \xrightarrow{\sim} K$.

Comment: @Nico It means that there is an non-real element conjugate to $x$. The notation means the degree (=dimension as $K$-vector space). What text book are you refering to ?

Comment: I think for the second point we can assume there exist $K$ such that $K(x)=\mathbb{C}$, and use the following result : A subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, denoted as $k$ such that $\mathbb{C}$ is a finite extension of k satisfied $[\mathbb{C}:k]=2$.

Answer (score 7):

There is no such number！ Suppose otherwise there is such a number $x\in \mathbb{R}$ with the property that there exists a proper subfield $K$ of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $K(x)=\mathbb{C}$. If $x$ is algebraic over $K$, then $\mathbb{C}$ is a finite extension of $K$. By Artin-Schreier theorem we know $K$ is just $\mathbb{R}$ which is impossible since $x\in \mathbb{R}$. If $x$ is transcendental over $K$, then $K(x)$ is not algebraically closed which is absurd since $K(x)=\mathbb{C}$.

There is a point to be make precise. In fact, by Artin Schreier theorem, if $x$ is algebraic over $K$, we actually get that $K$ is real closed. Therefore $K$ can be defined as the field of real numbers. So in this sense there is no such number $x$.

But if $\mathbb{R}$ is already choosed in $\mathbb{C}$, then the answer to the question is that such numbers are precisely real transcendental numbers.

First, let's show any real transcendental number $x$ can do. Choose a transcendental base $B$ of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. We may assume $B$ contains $x$. Consider the set $B'$ which is obtained from $B$ by repacing $x$ by $x+i$ and the other elements left unchanged, where $i\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $i^2=-1$. Then $B'$ is also a transcendental base of $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. So there exists an automorphism $\alpha : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $\alpha(x)=x+i$ and $\alpha(y)=y$ for any $x\neq y\in B$. Take $K=\alpha(\mathbb{R})$. Thus $i\notin K$ since $i\notin \mathbb{R}$ and $[\mathbb{C}:K]=2$. Now we know $x\notin K$ for otherwise $i=(x+i)-x \in K$. Therefore we know $K(x)=\mathbb{C}$.

Now, we are left only to show that any real algebaric number $x$ can not do. Suppose otherwise there is a real algebaric number $x$ with the desired property. Since $x$ is algebraic number we know the extension $\mathbb{C}/K$ is finite. Hence by Artin Schreier theorem $K$ is real closed. Thus we can find an isomorphism $\beta : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow K$. So all real conjugates including $x$ itself lies in $K$ which contradict to the fact $x\notin K$.

Comment: (To fill in a detail: the reason why $x$ transcendental implies $K(x)$ not algebraically closed is because $\sqrt{x}\notin K(k)$; for if it were, say $\sqrt{x} = p(x)$ for some $p$, then $x = p^2(x)$ and $p^2(x)-x=0$, contradicting the fact that $x$ was supposed to be transcendental.)

Comment: Thank you very much, but Artin-Schreier theorem is not in my cursus so I can't use this..Can we prove this result without this theorem ?

Comment: Maybe I'm just tired and I don't see it; but picking a transcendence basis $B$ for $\Bbb C$ over $\Bbb Q$, and some $x\in B\cap\Bbb R$; let $K=\Bbb Q(B\setminus\{x\})$ doesn't give the result?

Comment: Dear Asaf Karagila, if I understand your question correctly, I think in that case $K(x)\neq \mathbb{C}$. In fact $K(x)$ is no other than $K(B)$ which is not algebraically closed.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this theorem ? I think I have not found the right reference (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin–Schreier_theory)

Comment: Dear Nico, please try to seach "Real closed field" in wikipedia, which is also called the Artin Schreier theorem. Please note what you find is Artin-Schreier theory which is the additive version of Kummer theory. Or you can find the detailed treatment on this topic in Serge Lang's Algebra.

Comment: I found it. Thank you. (Please use @ when you offer to someone)

Comment: This answer is confusing; first you say that there are no values of $x$, then you say real transcendents are the values you can choose for $x$!

Comment: The ring $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_3 \sqrt[3]{2})$ is a formally real field, where $\zeta_3$ is a primitive cube root of unity, because it is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$. If $F$ is any real closure, then note $F(\sqrt[3]{2}) \cong \overline{\mathbf{Q}}$, despite $\sqrt[3]{2}$ being real algebraic!

Answer (score 4):

Building on the ideas in the comment, let us prove the following statement:

> Suppose that $K$ is a field and $t\notin K$ is transcendental over $K$, then $K(t)$ is not algebraically closed.

In particular, let us see that $\sqrt t\notin K(t)$, so $x^2-t$ doesn't have a root in $K(t)$. Assume otherwise, then $\sqrt t\notin K$ as well, because $t\notin K$. So by definition there is a rational function $h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ such that $h^2(x)=x$.

We have that $f^2(x)=x\cdot g^2(x)$. Let $n=\deg f$ and $m=\deg g$. Then we have $n^2=m^2+1$, so we have that $(n+m)(n-m)=1$. Since both are non-negative integers this means that $n=1$ and $m=0$, and therefore $f(x)=ax+b$, and $g(x)=c$ for some $a,b,c\in K$.

Therefore $\deg h=\deg f$ and so $\deg h^2=2\neq \deg x=1$. $\quad\square$

---

Now suppose that $x\in\Bbb R$, and $K$ is a proper subfield of $\Bbb C$ such that $K(x)=\Bbb C$, in particular $K(x)$ is algebraically closed. This is impossible if $x\notin K$, and therefore we have a contradiction since $K(x)\subseteq K\neq\Bbb C$.

Comment: Since field theory is not my forte, I'd be happy to hear comments from users whose field of expertise is closer to the topic.

Comment: This is not the comment that you expect for, I don't understand your statement when you said : let us see that. How can you see that ? Thanks.

Comment: Recall that the elements of $K(t)$ are essentially writing $t$ into rational function over $K$. So if $\sqrt t\in K(t)$ it is represented by such function.

Comment: And he cannot be represented because ? In fact you said $\sqrt{t} \notin K(t)$ and after 'Assume $\sqrt{t} \notin K$ because $t\notin K$'. You dumped me..

Comment: Nico, if $\sqrt t\in K$ then $(\sqrt t)^2\in K$.

Comment: When you said : Suppose that $K$ is a field and $t\notin K$ is transcendental over $K$ , then  $\dim_K\mathbb{C} = +\infty$, then none $x$ algebraic can satisfy  $K(x) = K[x] = \mathbb{C}$ ? Right ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: If I take $K=\mathbb{R}$ and $t=i\pi$ then $K(t)$ is algebraically closed no ?

Comment: But $i\pi$ is not transcendental over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: oh yes, sorry to waste your time.

Comment: It's fine, I'm too tired to work anyway. ;-)

Comment: So a last question..Therefore there is no such number ?

Comment: Well, if you use $K(x)$ to only denote transcendental extensions, then this is pretty much done; if you use it to denote algebraic extensions as well, then the argument is incomplete and I'll have to think about it a little bit more.

Comment: Yes $K(x)$ can denote algebraic extensions...

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to think about it a bit more.

Comment: Could you please tell me if you had the time to think about it ? Thanks

Comment: A little bit, but not enough as I wanted.